# Prove that $gAg^{-1} = A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G$ is a finite group and $A \leq G$ such that all double cosets $AxA$ have the same number of elements.  Show that $gAg^{-1} =A,~\forall g \in G$.

There seem to be some similar problems posted on the website, but they are different than what I am trying to prove.  I've already proven in the same set of problems that $|AxB| = \frac{|A||B|}{|A \cap xBx^{-1}|}$ for all $x \in G$.  I feel like the two facts are connected, but I'm not sure how to get to the end result.

Comment: Substitute B=A in the result you already have. What does that tell you? (Also try substituting x=e.)

Answer (score 1):

From your proven fact it follows that $|A\cap xAx^{-1}| = |A|$ for each $x\in G$. This implies $A\subseteq xAx^{-1}$. Since $A$ and $xAx^{-1}$ have the same cardinality it follows $A=xAx^{-1}$.